# What is the proper way to use EVReflection to parse a Dictionary type?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using `EVReflection` in my app.  One JSON response should be parsed as type `Dictionary<String,Array<MyObject>>`.  I have successfully parsed this by overriding the `setValue` method like this:

```
override func setValue(_ value: Any!, forUndefinedKey key: String) {
    switch key {
    case "response":
        if let dict = value as? NSDictionary {
            response = Dictionary<String,Array<MyObject>>();
            for (key, value) in dict {
                var listValues = Array<MyObject>();
                if let array = value as? NSArray {
                    for vd in array {
                        listValues.append(MyObject(dictionary: vd as! NSDictionary));
                    }
                }
                response![key as? String ?? ""] = listValues;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

However, I am seeing the following error in the console:

> ERROR: Could not create an instance for type Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Swift.Array<MyObject>>

Is there a different way I should be doing this?  How do I get the error to go away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out by using a `propertyConverter` as follows:

```
override public func propertyConverters() -> [(key: String, decodeConverter: ((Any?) -> ()), encodeConverter: (() -> Any?))] {
    return[
        (
            key: "response"
            , decodeConverter: {
                if let dict = $0 as? NSDictionary {
                    self.response = Dictionary<String,Array<MyObject>>();
                    for (key, value) in dict {
                        var listValues = Array<MyObject>();
                        if let array = value as? NSArray {
                            for vd in array {
                                listValues.append(MyObject(dictionary: vd as! NSDictionary));
                            }
                        }
                        self.response![key as? String ?? ""] = listValues;
                    }
                }
              }
            , encodeConverter: { return nil }
        )
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `EVReflection` you should be using `NSDictionary` not a `Dictionary` (which is a struct).

If you do this then you shouldn't need to override any property converter methods.